# If possible, how can I automatically create a Many to Many class with a custom create function?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I came across a problem while creating an application. It essentially involves three different classes. The purpose is to create an object containing basic social media information for an artist, as the main model shows:

```
class ArtistSocial(models.Model):
artist = models.ForeignKey('core.Artist', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
social_network = models.ForeignKey('core.SocialNetwork', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
url = models.CharField(max_length=50)
created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
```

The premise of the challenge I'm faced with is that upon the creation of a new artist, I'll be sent a JSON with all the information I need. However, being quite new to programming applications like this, This makes me confused as to how exactly I need to prepare to properly receive that information and create the class. To me, making a custom create action was the clear solution, but I've tried this in many different ways both in ArtistSerializer and ArtistSocialSerializer. I don't have my previous attempts written down, but I recently moved on to try doing this with a custom action instead. I'll post the serializers and the action contained in the ArtistViewSet here:

```
class ArtistSerializer(ModelSerializer):
user = serializers.HiddenField(
    default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault()
)

class Meta:
    model = Artist
    fields = ['id', 'user', 'name_alternative', 'labels', 'tags',
              'country', 'bio', 'profile_image', 'created_at', 'updated_at']
    read_only_fields = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'user']
```

And here's the main one:

```
class ArtistSocialSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:

    model = ArtistSocial
    fields = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'artist', 'social_network', 'url']
    read_only_fields = ['id', 'created_at', 'updated_at']
```

The action in the viewset:

```
    @action(methods=['post'], detail=True)
def create_social(self, request, pk):
    artist = Artist.objects.get(pk=pk)
    social = ArtistSocial.objects.create(artist)
    return social
```

Though I assume this one isn't so relevant, I'll also send the other model involved:

```
class SocialNetwork(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
icon = models.CharField(max_length=50)
created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'SocialsNetwork'

def __str__(self):
    return '%s' % self.name
```

Currently, running the code, I get a TypeError message that says "create() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given". I'm struggling a bit to wrap my head around how actions work in Django Rest Framework.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Where is your "custom create method" that you've tried? What didn't work exactly? If you got an error, what's the error? Please make your problem specific, following the advice in how to make a [mcve].

Comment: I've added a custom action instead, which is my latest attempt. By the time I posted this question, I had ended up dumping the custom create piece of code.

Comment: when you do `create()` you need to specify all required fields of the model as name arguments: `ArtistSocial.objects.create(artist=artist, social_network=..., url=...)`.

Comment: That's what's got me a bit confused. The front-end will send me a JSON with all the information I need, but how can I extract it? I was told validated_data in ArtistSerializer would likely include it, but while I was debugging a previous create I realized that wasn't really the case. I'm not sure how to assign each thing included in the JSON in its respective field.